# Localisation Discrete valuation

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

**Question**

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $P$ a non zero prime ideal in $R[x]$ such that $P\cap R=(0)$. Then show that $R[x]_{P}$ is a discrete valuation ring.

**Attempt**

$R[x]_{P}$ is a local ring and an integral domain as $R$ is. However it is not clear to me how every ideal of $R[x]_{P}$ is principal or how is this ring even Noetherian.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where have you used $P\cap R=0$?

Comment: I am not sure how to use it. Any hints?

Comment: Show that $R[x]_P=K[x]_P$ where $K$ is the fraction field of $R$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohan.